# Can i use shortand if else statement in my code

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have one question about shortand if else statement. I just want to learn how can i shortand my js if else statement. Anyone can help me within example using my code ?

I am checking the code if clicked button rel="Like" or other text then do something withing if else statement.

```
if (REL === 'Like') {
   if (!$('#pli' + dataid).length) {
      $('#ttl' + dataid).prepend('<div class="pli" id="pli' + dataid + '"></div>');
   }
} else if (REL === 'Love') {
   if (!$('#plo' + dataid).length) {
      $('#ttl' + dataid).prepend('<div class="plo" id="plo' + dataid + '"></div>');
   }
}else if (REL === 'Unbelievable') {
   if (!$('#phi' + dataid).length) {
      $('#ttl' + dataid).prepend('<div class="phi" id="phi' + dataid + '"></div>');
   }
}else if (REL === 'Spectacular') {
   if (!$('#pha' + dataid).length) {
      $('#ttl' + dataid).prepend('<div class="pha" id="pha' + dataid + '"></div>');
   }
}else if (REL === 'Emotional') {
   if (!$('#pwo' + dataid).length) {
      $('#ttl' + dataid).prepend('<div class="pwo" id="pwo' + dataid + '"></div>');
   }
}

if (REL === 'NotLike') {
   setTimeout(function() {
      if ($("#sum" + dataid).text() == 0) {
         $("#pli" + dataid).remove();
      }
   }, 200);
}else if (REL === 'NotLove') {
   setTimeout(function() {
      if ($("#sum" + dataid).text() == 0) {
         $("#plo" + dataid).remove();
      }
   }, 200);
}else if (REL === 'NotUnbelievable') {
   setTimeout(function() {
      if ($("#sum" + dataid).text() == 0) {
         $("#phi" + dataid).remove();
      }
   }, 200);
}else if (REL === 'NotSpectacular') {
   setTimeout(function() {
      if ($("#sum" + dataid).text() == 0) {
         $("#pha" + dataid).remove();
      }
   }, 200);
}else if (REL === 'NotEmotional') {
   setTimeout(function() {
      if ($("#sum" + dataid).text() == 0) {
         $("#pwo" + dataid).remove();
      }
   }, 200);
}
```

Comment: You can use a `switch` statement based on `rel` value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Switch will definitely help make the code cleaner and more readable. Also I would suggest making a map, a lot of the code is duplicated.

below is an example

```
if ( [ 'Like', 'Love', 'Unbelievable', 'Spectacular', 'Emotional' ].indexOf( REL ) !== -1 ) {
    var map = { 'Like': 'pli', 'Love': 'plo', 'Unbelievable': 'phi' };
    if ( !$( '#' + map[ REL ] + dataid ).length ) {
        $( '#ttl' + dataid).prepend( '<div class="' + map[ REL ] + '" id="' + map[ REL ] + dataid + '"></div>' );
    }
}

if ( [ 'NotLike', 'NotLove', 'NotUnbelievable', 'NotSpectacular', 'NotEmotional' ].indexOf( REL ) !== -1 ) {
    var map = { 'NotLike': 'pli', 'NotLove': 'plo', 'NotUnbelievable': 'phi' };
    setTimeout( function () {
        if ( $('#sum' + dataid).text() == 0 ) {
            $( '#' + map[ REL ] + dataid ).remove();
        }
    }, 200 );
}
```

Comment: this is better then case. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

How about using a dictionary like:

```
var dict = {'Like': 'pli','Love': 'plo','Unbelievable':'phi','Emotional':'pwo'};

if (dict[REL]) {
  if (!$('#'+dict[REL] + dataid).length) {
    $('#ttl' + dataid).prepend('<div class="' + dict[REL] + '" id="'+ dict[REL] + dataid + '"></div>');
  }
}
```

It can help you reduce the size of both of your ifs

Answer (score 2):

I would argue that `object` is much more readable then either `switch` or `if/else`.

```
var map = {
  Like: 'pli',
  Love: 'plo',
  Unbelievable: 'phi',
  Spectacular: 'pha',
  Emotional: 'pwo'
};

var className = map[REL];

if (className) {
  if (!$('#' + className + dataid).length) {
     $('#ttl' + dataid).prepend('<div class="' + className + '" ' +
                                     'id="' + className + dataid + '"></div>');
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

As others have stated you want a *switch-case* statement:

```
switch (REL){
    case 'Like':
        if (!$('#pli' + dataid).length) {
            $('#ttl' + dataid).prepend('<div class="pli" id="pli' + dataid + '"></div>');
        break;
    case 'Love':
        if (!$('#plo' + dataid).length) {
            $('#ttl' + dataid).prepend('<div class="plo" id="plo' + dataid + '"></div>');
        break;
    case 'Unbelievable':
        if (!$('#phi' + dataid).length) {
            $('#ttl' + dataid).prepend('<div class="phi" id="phi' + dataid + '"></div>');
        break;
    case 'Spectacular':
        if (!$('#pha' + dataid).length) {
            $('#ttl' + dataid).prepend('<div class="pha" id="pha' + dataid + '"></div>');
        break;
    case 'Emotional':
        if (!$('#pwo' + dataid).length) {
            $('#ttl' + dataid).prepend('<div class="pwo" id="pwo' + dataid + '"></div>');
        break;
    case 'NotLike':
        setTimeout(function() {
            if ($("#sum" + dataid).text() == 0) {
                $("#pli" + dataid).remove();
            }
        }, 200);
        break;
    case 'NotLove':
        setTimeout(function() {
            if ($("#sum" + dataid).text() == 0) {
                $("#plo" + dataid).remove();
            }
        }, 200);
        break;
    case 'NotUnbelievable':
        setTimeout(function() {
            if ($("#sum" + dataid).text() == 0) {
                $("#phi" + dataid).remove();
            }
        }, 200);
        break;
    case 'NotSpectacular':
        setTimeout(function() {
            if ($("#sum" + dataid).text() == 0) {
                $("#pha" + dataid).remove();
            }
        }, 200);
        break;
    case 'NotEmotional':
        setTimeout(function() {
            if ($("#sum" + dataid).text() == 0) {
                $("#pwo" + dataid).remove();
            }
        }, 200);
        break;
    default:
        //do something or nothing
}
```